# How can print pictures subcaption in margin?

Tags: margins, subcaption

In `biditufte-handout` class, the caption of figure will apear in margin.
I like it. It is nice.
Now I want to force LaTex to print subcaption in margin.
Hoe can I do this?

```
\documentclass{biditufte-handout}
\usepackage{ptext} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xepersian}
 \settextfont{Yas}
\reversemarginpar
\begin{document} 
\section{یک عنوان بخش}
\ptext[1]
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig1}
\caption{یک عنوان شکل آزمایشی}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
 \ptext[8]
\begin{figure}
        \centering
        ~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc.
      %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth , height=.75\textwidth]{fig1}
            \caption{زاویه سوم ($\psi$)}
            \label{نمودار زاویه سوم جسم صلب}
    \end{subfigure}%
    ~
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth , height=.75\textwidth]{fig1}
            \caption{زوایای اویلر تحت گشتاور نامتقارن}
            \label{زوایای اویلر تحت گشتاور نامتقارن}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{نمودار جسم صلب}\label{نمودار جسم صلب2}
\end{figure}
\ptext[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: How precisely should things look like?  Usually, subfigures are posted next to each other, and the point of `subcaption` is to place the subcaptions right under the corresponding subfigures.  If you don't need to place the subcaptions under the subfigures, then you don't need to use the package `subcaption`.   Just write the whole text into the ordinary caption (and make it clear what describes the left or the right figure).

Comment: You're right. I think this is best way.